# I want to use the 'convmv' command to change Title and Artist

Tags: command-line, 19.10, unicode

I used convmv to change the unicode of the file.
 But Title and Artist cannot change it.
I want to change the title and artist.

```
convmv -r --notest -f TIS620 -t UTF-8 *
```

[image]

Comment: `convmv` converts filenames from one encoding to another, not metadata - Please [edit] your question and tell us what type of files you are wroking on. (flac, mp3, video, other?) - Feel free to put a full command line example.

Comment: your screen shit does not smell like Ubuntu ...

Comment: @cmak.fr mp3 Brother

Comment: @cmak.fr https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3hh3.jpg my screen on windows checked in mp3tag program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convmv` converts filenames from one encoding to another, not metadata

---

**[id3v2](https://github.com/myers/id3v2)** is CLI a editor (read/write) for audio tags, based on [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/)

```
sudo apt install id3v2
```

Usage example
 - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47892/id3v2-used-recursively-at-command-line

---

**[eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** is another (the one i prefer) CLI tags editor

```
sudo apt install eyed3
```

Usage example
 - https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html
 - https://code-examples.net/en/q/22f4

---

The GUI program **easytag** to batch-write audio file's tags
In the app, there is an option about encoding for tags reading
And another option to choose the encoding when writing tags

```
sudo apt-get install easytag
```

[image]
https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG

Comment: Can I use the command line only to fix it? I don't have an ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @taro see edited answser

Comment: Thanks brother. Now I can fix it.